# Using bmargin to remove whitespace

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I interpret [this](https://sv.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins) as telling me that `bmargin` is what removes the whitespace between the bottom of the document and the bottom figures. But if you run the code you will see that the whitespace is still there, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I just noticed that the second page had correctly `bmargin=0`. How do I get this to work on the first page aswell?

EDIT2 (answer to comment): The reason I use that particular `voffset` is just to make it look a bit more centered, ideally I would like to control the exact `voffset` and `bmargin` on the first page, it seems like I can do it on every other page but not the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperheight=830pt, voffset=60pt, bmargin=0pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:numberthree}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:numberfour}
    \end{subfigure}
    \label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT3:** This code is for my answer in the comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperheight=830pt, voffset=20pt, bmargin=50pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{fig:numberthree}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \label{fig:numberfour}
    \end{subfigure}
    \label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a great product! :)

Comment: sure, see edit.

Comment: @JohnKormylo when I wrote `\vspace*{\fill}`, the pictures went under the first page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo See new edit. When I run the code with `\vspace*{\fill}`, it gets under the first page. But if I add `bmargin=50pt`, it comes in to the page again, but now there's a big gap between the second and third row of figures. Is there any way to remove that, or fill it with 2 more figures to make it look symmetric?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I get the feeling that standalone might be a better solution (although it doesn't support figure).  Also, without captions, those labels will do nothing (or just show the page number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[paperheight=830pt, margin=0pt, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\@fptop=0pt% distance from top of text area to first [p] figure
\@fpbot=0pt% distance from bottom of text area to last [p] figure.
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:numberthree}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:numberfour}
    \end{subfigure}
    \label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:numberthree}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:numberfour}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:pics2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this, just have to figure out how that code works between `makeatletter` and `makeatother`. By the way, it seems like the code works just as good without the `noheadfoot`.

Comment: You don't need `\pagestyle{empty}` either, since all of that would be outside the edges of the page.  See source2e.pdf from CTAN for `\fp@top` etc.